# Resource limit matched monit ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, monit

I have an small rails 3 app on a small linode 512 mb and I make the monitoring with monit my rails app.

I can see on monit the message `Resource limit matched`. You can see the next image:

http://overpic.net/viewer.php?file=x5d6ybfukwgz6a5845bu8.jpg

I'm newbie with monit.

**Does this mean that I should increase my ram memory? or my cpu? or upgrade to linode 1GB?**

**Where can I find a good monit ebook?**

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell what rails is doing, but it looks like you have memory leaks in unicorn and DJ if the Linode slice is using 0% CPU and 87% memory.  Do some profiling and look at logs of the controllers and models and correlate which of their methods are driving up memory usage over past 24 hours

Comment: ... and post actual monit config, it's impossible to say which limit was matched